# Deployment script for apim call to function app

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment

Im having problems with an apim arm deplyment script. Im looking at the export template to try and figure how to construct the script. Problem is i need to do it dynamically and the export template is full of hard coded values. So im trying to figure out what is what. The error message i get is

```
  "details": [
  {
    "code": "ValidationError",
    "target": "set-backend-service",
    "message": "Error in element 'set-backend-service' on line 4, column 6: Backend with id 'tostore-functionapp' could not be found."
  }
```

Im having troubles understanding where i can find this backendId and what it should be set to. The only thing i can think of is a resource of type Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/backends. But it has no ID property. The only thing that is set to 'tostore-functionapp' is its description and if i change it it still works.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it seems like the backend has not been created beforehand. It needs to be declared first, so that API manager can find it.

For details please check below similar threads.

[Azure API management and App Function backend: Backend with id 'foo' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879254/azure-api-management-and-app-function-backend-backend-with-id-foo-could-not-b)

[Error in element 'set-backend-service' Backend with id 'backendId' could not be found](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/48421)

Comment: It is declared first. I solved it by removing the backend resource. It wasn't needed.